# How to make header of a DataList repeat on each column when using RepeatColumn?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, header, datalist

I need to display the records in a view on more than one column for better visibility so i switched from using GridView to DataList.

How can I make the DataList repeat the header on each column? Currently it only sets header on first column.

Result should look something like this:

[image: example result]

I would prefer a solution using DataList, but might switch to Repeater if it is done easier that way.

Thanks for replies!